# google mock - EXPECT_CALL triggers even though function has different argument

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have `EXPECT_CALL(MockObj, func("abc")).Times(1)` and `MockObj` is a `NiceMock`

In my function under test, there is a call `MockObj.func("def")` *in addition to* `MockObj.func("abc")`.

I would expect that the reasonable thing to do is for Google Mock to say

> oh look we call `func("def")` but the arguments do not match the
>   `EXPECT_CALL`; nothing to see here

But instead it "complains":

> unknown file: Failure
>
> Unexpected mock function call - taking default action specified at:
>
> C:/work/unit_test.cpp:36:
>
> ```
> Function call: func(84bf3d9 pointing to "def")
>
>       Returns: 1
> ```
>
> Google Mock tried the following 1 expectation, but it didn't match:
>
> unit_test.cpp:50: EXPECT_CALL(MockObj, func("abc"))...
>
> Expected arg #0: is equal to 84c8b96 pointing to "abc"
>
> Actual: 84bf479 pointing to "def"
>
> Expected: to be called once
>
> Actual: called once - saturated and active

First notice that the expectation was still satisfied because `MockObj.func("abc")` was called

I understand why GMock threw the error: I declared an expection on `func` so it tried to match the call to `func` to the expectation but it didn't match the arguments so **error**

Fine.

But why does GMock throw an **error**? Since the arguments don't match, why was this behavior selected i.e.

> throw an error if the function matches existing `EXPECT_CALL` but not the arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question "But why does GMock throw an error? " is: because it is designed that way.

AFAIU googlemock - the googlemock in your case works this way:

1. `EXPECT_CALL(MockObj, func("abc"));` - means: "I am interested in `Obj::func` in my tests"
2. `MockObj`  being `NiceMock` means: "I do not care about any other functions of `Obj` that are not explicit subject of EXPECT_CALL"

So - if your code-under-test calls `func("def")` - then google-mock does that:

1. we are interested in `func` - so let's check
2. we do not expect "def" - so fail the test

Probably you know that you should do this:

`EXPECT_CALL(MockObj, func(StrNe("abc"))).Times(AnyNumber()); // meaning - do not care
EXPECT_CALL(MockObj, func("abc")); // TImes(1) is default - you might skip it`